Como deshabilito realmente el autosave en visual studio code porque siempre me guarda al darle run a un script
He instalado totalmente desde 0  visual studio code y  python en una PC sin ninguna otra cosa recién formateada con windows 11 pero igualmente cuando hago la instalación de visual studio code y creo un script me pide obviamente instalar la extensión de python, lo hago y ejecuto el script pero de una vez me lo guarda sin mi consentimiento, Cada vez que ejecuto un script de python en visual studio code me lo guarda sin mi permiso he desactivado las opciones de autoguardado y consultado en internet pero aún así sigue guardándolo solo pasa cuando lo ejecuto, porque si estoy escribiendo y modificando el código y cierro python sin guardar el archivo cuando vuelvo a abrir visual studio code el archivo aparece como que no ha sido guardado pero basta con que yo presione el botón de play o run y de una vez me guarda el archivo sin mi autorización, como dije no hay mas nada instalado solo windows, visual studio code, python y su extensión ( todo esta en su última versión)

Si los cambios no se guardaran, al intentar ejecutar se utilizaría la versión que está en disco y por lo tanto no se ejecutaría lo que tienes actualmente en el editor.

ok te entiendo y gracias por responder pero el año pasado ejecutaba el codigo con el mas mimimo cambio y sin guardar además cuando modifico el script y depuro el no lo guarda solo lo hace cuando le doy run.
lo que quiero es que pueda editarlo y toquetear sin guardar hasta estar seguro de los cambios

Si tienes control de versiones no tendrías por qué tener problemas con el hecho de guardar constantemente el archivo. Y si no lo tienes bajo control de versiones VSCode tiene la pestaña Timeline que trackea todos los cambios que haces a un archivo de forma local, sin necesidad de nada externo. VS Code Timeline — Your local version control system
